# Options for wifi 250 meters from house with no power at destination?

Tags: wireless-networking, wds

I have a tree farm in a cell coverage dead spot.  I do have internet.  I would like to spread wifi out to cover the show areas of the farm.

There is no power at the show area.

The distance is about 250 meters.

There is no power at the show areas.

Is there a reasonably priced option to put an access point in the show area?

Comment: Three things: 
1) Techinical: WiFi does not reach that far from a single AP. SO you are going to need local access points. Those will use power. That either means either laying power cables or something battery/solar powered.
2) Site local: Product recommendations are off-topic. See our FAQ.
3) Just what is reasonably priced will vary a great deal per person. Those kinds of questions are very hard to answer. Esp. if a higher priced products might have more capabilities.

Comment: @hennes I agree, but I can provide some suggestions (without specific product recommendations) as I have been in the same spot last year. Writing up an answer now.

Comment: Just remember that if the trees are too densely planted, it may be difficult or impossible to achieve decent coverage by any means.

Comment: I'm thinking 250 meters of string and some paper cups.  Everything about your situation would seem to be a problem for the typical low-cost solutions.  How difficult would it be to bury some kind of cable?

Comment: The paper cup to ethernet converter module is too pricey.  Most of the distance between is poplar bush.  Trenching a cable would be difficult due to roots.  A more plausible method is to hang it from the trees.

Comment: Water (trees are full of water) is a Wi-Fi killer. You must also remember that the client device needs to have the radio power and antenna to get back. Wi-Fi is a bidirectional protocol. Antenna gain and radio power is highly regulated, but it is looser for point-to-point links.

Comment: The plan is to run the cable to the middle of the display area where the trees are short.  At that point the entire area is within a 60 meter radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option for you as I can see - is to use higher gain antennas.
Without map where WiFi access point located and area that need to be covered it hard to tell what exact antenna(s) you need, but if you get directional antenna with 12-15dBi gain it should cover area you want in case you have straight sight between WiFi and show area. You also need to be make sure that
[fresnel zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_zone) isn't covered with obstacles that may reduce effectiveness of directional antenna(s). My personal record was 48 kilometers(with reduced WiFi speed to 1-11Mbps) when we need to connect two offices between each other with help of 24dBi directional antennas that had pretty narrow beam on both sides.

You can use multiple antennas with more than one WiFi access point to cover area you want because directional antennas has narrow beam coverage.

Anyway you would need some radio tools that need to setup such systems.

Answer (score 1):

That's going to be fairly expensive, but it can be done.
I've been in a similar position where I needed a link between 2 buildings 400 meters apart and had to cross a canal in between.

First you will need power:
Either solar-panel if your weather permits and you can find one with enough yield or a UPS unit that you charge overnight and wheel out to the farm during the day.
Small diesel or petrol generator may also be an option if you don't mind the noise. (Quit possible you already have one lying around on a farm.)

Second you will need the actual access-point.

And third: You need a pair of access-points (with directional antenna's) that are specifically designed to act as a point-2-point link.
One half of that pair you place need the access-point and the other half of that pair you install at the farm-house.
You are going to need a good line of sight between the to end-points of the point-2-point link. (Mounting them on poles so their line-of-sight is above peoples heads, tractors and other high equipment is probably best.

These wireless point-2-point pairs are usually sold as kits specific for such purpose. Often they have the option for a mains power-supply and for DC power (which might be easier to handle in combination with solar).
These things are not necessarily WiFi based. They can use other radio-spectrum (including frequencies you may need a permit for! Check your local regulations!) Some use Infra Red lasers for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

[Gigabit PoE+ Repeater](https://www.trendnet.com/products/poe-splitters-injectors-extenders/tpe-e100)

They run US $80 each, and can be daisy chained.  This particular is not outdoor rated, but a vented, screened weatherproof box is an hour in the shop.  Add an injector for $15-30, an outdoor access point $100, a spool of cat5e off of ebay for $60 and I potentially have a solution for under $400